# How to update and use state by event handler in React

Tags: reactjs

I have component Searcher with function SearchArticle() which is correctly using **this.state.search** with DEFAULT value after component mounts (console displaying *Searching...:DEFAULT*) . But when I update ***this.state.search*** with handleKeyPress(e) them same function SearchArticle() is using prev state before it updates to e.target value (console displaying *Searching...:DEFAULT* again). Not sure how to fix it.

```js
class Searcher extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            article: [], search: "DEFAULT"
        }; 
    }  

    searchArticle() { 
        console.log('Searching...: ', this.state.search)                                 
    }

    handleKeyPress = (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {                            
            this.setState({search: e.target.value});
            this.searchArticle();
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.searchArticle();     
    } 

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
            Search: <input onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} type="text" />
            </div>            
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely the state hasn't updated by the time the `console.log` is executed. This is because `setState()` is asynchronous.

So try this instead:

```
handleKeyPress = (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {                            
    this.setState({search: e.target.value}, () => {
       this.searchArticle();
    });       
  }
}
```

I moved your `searchArticle()` into the `setState()` callback. This will guarantee its execution *after* the state has actually updated.

---

Read more about `setState()` [**here**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

> Think of `setState()` as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall. Instead, use `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback (`setState(updater, callback)`), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.
>
> [...]
>
> The second parameter to `setState()` is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.